# RLM Residual in Python Statsmodel

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression, robust

I am trying to generate response type residual (y^-y)for RLM using statsmodel:

```
 model=smf.rllm('y~x', data=x)
 results=model.fit()
 resid=results.resid
```

I have generated residual using the above code. But it does not tie back with residual= `y - E(y|x)`. Is there a way to generate response type residual in RLM similar to GLM `(resid=results.resid_response)`?

Comment: You need to show an example to see what doesn't match. According to docs and code `resid = endog - fittedvalues` which is the usual response residual. There is also `sresid`, the scaled residual.

Comment: why is there a R tag?

Comment: RLM is more popularly used in R than python. So, thought it will increase the reach of question to such users and they might also be aware of statsmodel

Comment: @josef I am running RLM with a large dataset so producing example a bit difficult. I am running a weighted RLM in Python by multiplying both x &y by a weight vector. Simply, dividing the residual by the weight vector would not give the same result as they are not linearly related.

Comment: This is not an issue with your data. So, it should be possible to show an example with just using toy data, e.g. random generated data.